# Invalid redirect uri for QuickBlox user module's facebook login

Tags: quickblox

I am new to QuickBlox. I've just download the sample code from [SimpleSample-chat users-ios](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios) and connect it with my application on QuickBlox.

It works fine with the registration and normal login.

However, error occurred if I use facebook login. 
Error code 191:

> Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Edited on 2012-12-05:
After reading the manual, I've change my facebook app setting as follow:
[image: Facebook App Setting]
And I've filled in the App id and secret key on QuickBlox as follow:
[image: QuickBlox social integration setting]

However, I still get the invalid url error.

Note:
I have do no changes on the sample but the these few lines with my QuickBlox app's info:

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:xxx];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationKey:@"yyyyyyyy"];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"zzzzzzzzz"];
```

Any steps I missed to make that sample work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPD:**
This is an old guide and you don't need to configure social integration via Admin panel anymore. Use API to login a user with Facebook/Twitter.

===================

In order to use QuickBlox Social API (Twitter/Facebook) you have to:

1. Create Facebook/Twitter application
2. While registering the application supply Callback Url:

   - http://api.quickblox.com/auth/facebook/callback for Facebook
   - http://api.quickblox.com/auth/twitter/callback for Twitter
3. Enable social integration on your QuickBlox application (on [admin panel](http://admin.quickblox.com)) - Enter auth credentials for the platform you want to enable

Also you can follow [QuickBlox Social Networks Integration Manual](http://quickblox.com/developers/Social_Networks_Integration_Manual)

Comment: After following the manual, it still fails.
I've set the callback url for "Website with Facebook Login"
but fail.
And then I tried to set the canvas url as https://api.quickblox.com/auth/facebook/callback/,
https://api.quickblox.com/auth/facebook/callback?a=1,
https://api.quickblox.com/
but still get the that error.
Anyway, thanks for the lovely manual.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added more detail in my question.

Comment: could you try 'http' (not 'https') in callback url

Comment: Quickblox twitter secret key is not allowed to be more than 40 chars in admin panel!! What should be done ??

Comment: you don't need it anymore to configure via admin panel